# Any way to put in order automatically tables in Mysql Workbench diagram?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Hi have generated a new diagram connecting mysql workbench to database that already existed.

Now the tables are in a stack, one above each other, so i should drag and drop them to show a nice schema. But..is there any way to put in order automatically?

5.2.38

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To auto arrange the tables go to menu `Arrange -> Autolayout`

Comment: Seems that Autolayout functions strangely, it likes to arrange tables in bunches two or three on top of each other (that is if I select all), seems like a rather useless function.

Comment: If you don't want them on top of each other you should make more space for them. Go to File->Page Setup and change the size of you page like iso-a3 if it was a4. Then see the difference. If you have a lot of tables it can't auto layout them all right next to each other. Good luck.

Comment: I would also suggest highlighting all of the tables too be clicking autolayout

Comment: It is strange that I can't see any edit history on this answer.

Comment: Because it was edited within first several minutes, so the edit was not recorded.

Answer (score 26):

Go to

> Model-> Diagram Properties and Size

There increase the size by pages to whatever you want. Then go to

> Arrange -> Autolayout

This should help!!

Comment: If the tables are still not getting arranged then you need to select all the tables , for that click on the top-left corner of the diagram and drag the mouse to the bottom-right corner of the diagram . All tables will get selected , now do Arrange -> Autolayout again